# What is the best “all-in-one” REST API framework for MariaDB/MySQL to use with Vue/Nuxt.js frontend?

Tags: api, mysql, node.js, rest, mariadb

So I'm developing with Nuxt.js on frontend and I need to know what you think is the best REST API framework availible.

For the moment I use REST API that I developed myself and call it with axios in frontend. I would like to know if there are some API framework with an easy way to create routes, link them to tables and make user Read/Write check on them.

It can be working in Node.js or PHP, it has to work with MariaDB.

I saw feathers.js that to do the job and have an easy Vue.js frontend implementation https://vuex.feathersjs.com .

I would just like to know you guidance, so I invest my time in an appropriate solution for me.

Thanks in advance :)